# How can I do: "As the the record button is pressed, the button will be flashing"

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jquery-ui, cordova

I am developing a voice recorder function with PhoneGap on Android system. I'm testing on the Transformer Prime. I'm using jQuery and jQuery UI on top of PhoneGap's JavaScript.

My question is this: When the user presses the Record button, how can I make that button flash to indicate that the app is recording?

Of course, the effect I want to create is to let the user know it's still recording. Maybe I can set a timer to give the current recording duration, or something to that effect.

Unfortunately, I don't know one of these effects. Could anyone give me a suggestion with the  source code so that I can take it as a reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS for that: http://jsfiddle.net/fszhJ/. Have a keyframe that sets the element invisible for the first half of the time, and visible for the other half. (You may want add other prefixes than only `-webkit-`.)

```
@-webkit-keyframes keyframe {
    from {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    50% {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    to {
        visibility: visible;
    }
}

div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: black;
    -webkit-animation: keyframe 1s infinite;
}​
```

Comment: But, if I wanna the user presses "stop"(stop recording.). And the glow stops. Will this work?

Comment: Sorry, it seems that the link fails...
And how can I combine this to my code:
    I set the button image: <button id= "record", value="Record", ontouchstart="record_btn_Clicked()"> <image src= "../pic/record.png" width= 40px, height= 40px> </button> And I write an associated function to the record button in the js file: function record_btn_Clicked(){ if(rec.val() == 'Record'){ alert("To record"); rec.val("Stop"); } else if(rec.val() == 'Stop'){ alert("To stop"); rec.val("Record"); } }
I want to as the user touch(on the pad) the pad, it start to glow,and as he press it again. It stops.

Comment: @Stallman: The link works fine for me and does exactly what you describe.

Comment: I'm sorry... I still can't understand how to combine your code
to my code shown above. Could you give me more hint?
"I want that as the user press the record icon, the image of the icon starts to glow, and as he/she press it again the glowing stops." Of course, As the user press the record icon, it will prompt  a Dialog to tell him it's recording and then vanishes quickly. 
Sorry, I just need more hint...

Comment: @Stallman: As you can see in the fiddle, the code `$("#child").css("-webkit-animation", "none");` stops the animation whereas `$("#child").css("-webkit-animation", "keyframe 1s infinite");` starts it again. It can easily be done with a button, too: http://jsfiddle.net/fszhJ/5/.

Comment: Thank you... Ok... I'll try it "again" tomorrow, and I'll work hard to address that issue tomorrow since I need to handle another project now.

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery you can put a glow png above your record button (initially with opacity 0) and inside your interval animation you can do this:

```
 isVisible = false;

 var interval = setInterval(function(){

     opacityValue = isVisible ? 0 : 1;
     glow.css( 'opacity',  opacityValue );
     isVisible = !isVisible;

 }, 500);
```

And then, when you want stop it:

```
 clearInterval( interval );
```

if you want that your glow appears smoothly you can use css transitions.

Comment: Um... I'm trying since I can't combine your code to mine, now...
Whatever, thanks.

Comment: Sorry... What is "glow"(glow.css)? The pic name? So do I have to load it in .js file?

Comment: No. glow is the jQuery variable which represent your img object in DOM. You can initialize it doing: var glow = $( 'img.glow' );

Comment: Is "img" a directory, and glow.png is a picture under that?
I set the button image:
<button id= "record", value="Record", ontouchstart="record_btn_Clicked()">
 <image src= "../pic/record.png"  width= 40px, height= 40px>
</button>
And I write an associated function to the record button in the js file: 
function record_btn_Clicked(){
 if(rec.val() == 'Record'){
  alert("To record");
  rec.val("Stop");
 }
 else if(rec.val() == 'Stop'){
  alert("To stop");
  rec.val("Record");
 }
}

But, I don't know how can I combine your code to mine. 
I'm a beginner. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: I'm sorry... I still can't understand how to combine your code
to my code shown above. Could you give me more hint?
"I want that as the user press the record icon, the image of the icon starts to glow, and as he/she press it again the glowing stops." Of course, As the user press the record icon, it will prompt  a Dialog to tell him it's recording and then vanishes quickly. 
Sorry, I just need more hints...